# log4net, Castle Windsor, and the Application_Error method in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net, castle-windsor

I followed the [tutorial to setup log4net](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Five-Adding-logging-support.ashx) using the Windsor container.  Like the tutorial, I setup the LoggerInstaller class:

```
public class LoggerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
            f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.Log4net)
                  .WithConfig("log4net.config"));
    }
}
```

In the Global.asax, I have the following methods:

```
private static void BootStrapContainer()
{
    container = new WindsorContainer()
        .Install(FromAssembly.This());
    var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    BootStrapContainer();
}
```

And the ILogger type to be injected:

```
public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
```

This works fine on Controllers that have the ILogger property but I can't seem to get it to inject in the Global.asax.  What I want to do, is log unhandled exceptions in the Application_Error method like so:

```
void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    Logger.Error("App_Error", ex);
}
```

The LoggerInstaller is being called during Application_Start() but isn't injecting.  Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure it's probably something simple I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

"Logger" won't be injected into "global.asax" because that class has not been created (that cannot be done) through Windsor/IoC Container.

If you need logger within "Application_Error" I might suggest you to create your container within "Application_Start", keep it private into "global.asax" class and use Resolve/Release approach within "Application_Error" method

```
void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException(); 

    var logger = _container.Resolve<ILogger>();
    logger.Error("App_Error", ex);    
    _container.Release(logger);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach, however when assigning value: `var logger = _container.Resolve<ILogger>();` the logger instance doesn't seem to be configured properly and doesn't log as per my log4net.config settings.  I'm creating the container during Application_Start()...any thoughts?

Comment: Are you able to run successfuly my snippet code? Is ILogger been resolved successfully? Do you have log4net.config at application root level? Did you verify log4net.config settings?

Comment: Your code compiles and runs fine but the ILogger (which is from the castle namespace, not the log4net native type), doesn't seem to be configuring correct.  The log4net.config is in the root directory and works fine when used in the controller methods.  Haven't had a ton of time to get the problem squared away.